# AirbBag and 4x4 light is on after changing BMW X3 battery. Why?

Tags: battery, maintenance, bmw, supplemental-restraint-system

After I changed my BMW X3 2008 battery at home the `4x4` and `AirBag` light is on. Any ideas why?

*Some people [claim](http://www.e90post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=458022) that changing BMW x3 battery is not straight forward, however, they don't explicitly mention what, exactly, is different compared to regular cars.*

Comment: Its common. Usually goes away in a day or less. If not, you need to have the truck reset by the dealer or bmw mechanic. This has a good explanation: http://www.e90post.com/forums/showpost.php?p=8558474&postcount=80 Not your same model but it applies.

Comment: @racefever You were right. While the car was idling the light was on. However, once I drove around for 5 minutes it did turn off. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: No worries! I'm just glad your truck is back to normal. ^_^

Comment: @racefever can you post your comment as the answer?  Clearly you were correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its common. Usually goes away in a day or less. If not, you need to have the truck reset by the dealer or bmw mechanic. This has a good [explanation.](http://e90post.com/forums/showpost.php?p=8558474&postcount=80) Not your same model but it applies.

Answer (score 5):

The standard battery is an absorbed glass mat type (AGM). It is to be "registered" with a scan tool. If this is not done the vehicle can adjust to the new battery on its own. When the battery registration procedure is not performed several effects are seen; they include trouble codes in modules or the system can be put into "transport mode" in which whole systems can be disabled. The most common is that the hvac system is disabled. A battery saver should not be used on these vehicles as it will most likely blow the fuse for module memories.

BMW is trying to use this system to predict when the battery reaches near the end of its useful life. It is called the "intelligent battery system". A regular lead acid battery can be installed but you must tell the computer that you switched types. In more recent years they have improved the system further; it now requires a genuine BMW battery and they removed the switch to lead acid option at that time.

Comment: Your answer in the current form does not mention AirBag or 4x4 light at all. Can you edit it?